# CSS3 font family doesn't work in safari

Tags: css, fonts, font-family

I have a problem changing the `font-family` of my `h1` and `p` tags. The fonts work fine in Internet Explorer and Firefox, but in **mobile** Safari they turn in to *Arial*.

```
h1 {
    font-family: Cambria, "Times New Roman";
}

.text_1 {
    font-family: Cambria, "Times New Roman";
}
```

`p` and `h1` are placed in the same floated container with auto height.

Any tips?

Comment: are you loading Cambria font files??

Comment: Is the font present/installed on your device? if not installed it will show the default font used by your system or browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right away, we can see that only one of the displayed fonts overlaps: Arial. None of the Calibri or Cambria fonts are available on the Mac, and the Mac has at least a dozen just on this page that aren’t available in Windows!
In fact, between these two systems, there are only ten fonts that overlap:
[image]